# Copy table structure and change one column name

Tags: mysql, sql, database, primary-key

I am given the following table:

Students

- Student_ID VARCHAR(50) PRIMARY KEY
- Name VARCHAR(50)
- Adres VARCHAR(150)

Now I want to copy the tables structure, but change `Student_ID` to `Teacher_ID`.

The teachers table should look like this:

- Teacher_ID VARCHAR(50) PRIMARY KEY
- Name VARCHAR(50)
- Adres VARCHAR(150)

So far I have this line of code:

```
CREATE TABLE Teachers LIKE Students
```

Comment: I'm pretty sure you have to `CREATE TABLE` from scratch, and specify all the columns.

Comment: My teacher thinks otherwise :)

Comment: Homework is about Researching & Trying **NOT** Asking for answer

Comment: What you learn by searching and finding yourself will serve you all your life. What you learn by asking others will be forgotten forever few days after your next test. Love yourself and do your homework yourself.

Comment: I totally agree with Lorenz Meyer"s last comment, but I'm almost sure I could have not found this myself (or it should've taken days). Now I can continue with my work and not get behind my schedule

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
CREATE TABLE `Teachers` AS(
    SELECT Student_ID AS Teacher_ID, Name, Address FROM `Students` );
```

- http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/create-table-select.html

Comment: TeacherAs should be Teachers, I made a typo but changed it :)

Comment: Wouldn't you lose any metadata on the table?  `NOT NULL` constraints, default values, foreign keys, etc?

Comment: @MikeChristensen I believe so.  But this answers the question he had.  You'd have to go back and re-add those.

Comment: Oh, I didn't check if the keys and default values had to be copied too... Is it much difference in code?

Answer (score 2):

```
SHOW CREATE TABLE Students
```

will give you the create table query for Students. Make the necessary replacements.

Comment: That would also be a solution, but not the one I was asked, still helpful tho

Answer (score 0):

CREATE TABLE Teachers
AS (select Student_ID AS Teacher_ID, Name, Adres from  where 1=0);

Comment: @Eric Hotinger
I am not sure how that works. it copies the data to into the new table.  As per the requirement only schema should be copied.  Let me know if I am wrong.

Answer (score 0):

Copy the table structure, then change Student_ID to Teacher_ID.

```
CREATE TABLE Teachers LIKE Students;

ALTER TABLE Teachers CHANGE Student_ID Teacher_ID VARCHAR(50) PRIMARY KEY;
```

Source: [geoffreyhale/sql/#copy-table](http://geoffreyhale.com/sql/#copy-table)